# How to delete flickr photo through delete permission

Tags: php, flickr

I want to delete a photo from flickr application with delete permission  but i am confused how to use delete permission, anyone suggest me with an example?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [flickr.photos.delete](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.delete.html) API method.